# I have a warning before runnig appium as DeprecationWarning. what is it?

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm, appium

Hiii,

I installed appium and when I run it there is a warning:

> (node:20247) [DEP0128] DeprecationWarning: Invalid 'main' field in
> '/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/lib/node_modules/appium/node_modules/mjpeg-server/package.json'
> of './lib/mpegserver'. Please either fix that or report it to the
> module author (Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the
> warning was created)

and when I run `node --trace-deprecation ...` on my terminal it gives me back:

> node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:944   throw err;   ^
>
> Error: Cannot find module '/home/X/...'
> at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:941:15)
> at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:774:27)
> at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:76:12)
> at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',   requireStack: [] }

what's the problem here and how can I solve it?!

I'm using ubuntu 18.4. And node (v16.2.0)/ npm version(7.13.0).

Answer (score 5):

It's not an error, it's a warning that `mjpeg-server`, a package you're using, needs updating.

You don't need to worry about it.

(The subsequent error is due to you literally running `node --trace-deprecation ...` without replacing `...` with something else.)

Comment: Ah I see! Thanks a lot. Could please tell me how can I update this specific package?!

Answer (score 0):

Try to uninstall your `html-webpack` plugin and install the latest version or upgrade to the latest version for the fix.

It may be CLI outdated and the below one will list all deprecation

```
node --trace-deprecation ./node_modules/.bin/the_library_name_here
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify the 'main' field in `package.json` as follows:

```
"main": "./lib/mjpeg-server",
```

This can solve your problem.